# How to do topic level sorting/counting with Kafka Streams running with multiple instances

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to Kafka Streams and looking for a way to order the streaming data across partitions. My sales data topic has 10 partitions and are partitioned based on the sold items. For example,  groceries goes to one partition, beverages goes to another partition. The requirement is to find out top 5 sold items every 15 min. Now if i run 10 instances on 10 nodes,  each partition will be served with one dedicated consumer. In this case,  how can we find top 5 sold items across all partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use single-partition topic.

Kafka Streams inherits the scaling model from the brokers and consumers and thus only if you have a single-partition input topic you can process *all* data.

Cf: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#parallelism-model